# UIViewController viewWillAppear not called when adding as subView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, viewwillappear

I have a `UIViewController` that I am loading from inside another view controller and then adding its view to a `UIScrollView`.

```
self.statisticsController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StatisticsViewController"];
self.statisticsController.match = self.match;

[self.scrollView addSubview:self.statisticsController.view];
```

I've put breakpoints in the statistics view controller and `viewDidLoad` is being called but `viewWillAppear` isn't.

Is it because I'm not pushing it onto the hierarchy or something?

Comment: Yip, if a view is added as a subview, viewDidAppear will not be called. You could get around it by manually calling it from the parent views viewDidAppear method

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5470552/viewdidappear-for-subviews

Comment: Ah, I thought that might be the case. Thanks.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You should add `statisticsController` as a child view controller of the controller whose view you're adding it to.

```
self.statisticsController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StatisticsViewController"];
self.statisticsController.match = self.match;

[self.scrollView addSubview:self.statisticsController.view];
[self addChildViewController:self.statisticsController];
[self.statisticsController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

I'm not sure this will make `viewDidAppear` get called, but you can override `didMoveToParentViewController:` in the child controller, and that will be called, so you can put any code that you would have put in `viewDidAppear` in there.

Comment: Would this trigger viewDidAppear methods?

Comment: Hey! This works :D Thanks very much! @sbarow yes it triggers the viewWillAppear method.

Comment: This will only work on iOS 6, on iOS 5 you will have to call `viewWillAppear:` manually.

Comment: There should be [self.statisticsController willMoveToParentViewController:self] call before [self addChildViewController:self.statisticsController].

Comment: @RafałAugustyniak, That's not necessary, it's called automatically by the system. From the docs: "When your custom container calls the addChildViewController: method, it automatically calls the willMoveToParentViewController: method of the view controller to be added as a child before adding it."

Comment: trouble is ... **it triggers viewWillAppear twice!!** which sucks

Comment: Actually you must first `addChildViewController`, then `addSubview`.

Comment: you must first addChildViewController... @AlexanderVolkov is right.

Answer (score 49):

I encounter `-viewWillAppear:` not called problem again. After googling, I came here. I did some tests, and find out that the calling order of `-addSubview` and `-addChildViewController:` is important.

**Case 1.** will trigger `-viewWillAppear:` of controller, but **Case 2,** it **WON'T** call `-viewWillAppear:`.

Case 1:

```
  controller?.willMoveToParentViewController(self)

  // Call addSubview first
  self.scrollView.addSubview(controller!.view)
  self.addChildViewController(controller!)

  controller!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Case 2:

```
  controller?.willMoveToParentViewController(self)

  // Call adChildViewController first      
  self.addChildViewController(controller!)      
  self.scrollView.addSubview(controller!.view)

  controller!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: Interesting. This contradicts Apple's documentation in the view controller programming guide. You should file a bug.

Comment: This helped me.

Comment: Any update on this? Seems like a bug to me, but definitely ran into the same thing. Apple's documentation states case 2 is the correct way,
 and it makes more sense (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW13). Maybe I'll file a radar...

Comment: @SeeMeCode, please file a radar. :) I has not touched those codes about 1 year.

Comment: Case 2 seems to be working fine. (Xcode 9.3, Swift 4.1)

Comment: You have saved my day!

Comment: it doesn't seem like a bug. UIKit checks shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods flag and call willAppear inside viewWillMoveToWindow methods. If childController hasn't been added yet UIKit 'can't understand" added view is view of childController so there is not enough information to start "appearence forwarding".

Comment: I can add that this bug happened to us on iOS 10. Worked fine on iOS 11 later.

Answer (score 22):

By default, appearance callbacks are automatically forwarded to children.
It's determined with **shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods** property. Check value of this propery, if it's **NO** and if your child viewController should appear right on container's appearance, you should notify child with following methods in container's controller life-cycle implementation:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    for (UIViewController *child in self.childViewControllers) {
        [child beginAppearanceTransition:YES animated:animated];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self.child endAppearanceTransition];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    for (UIViewController *child in self.childViewControllers) {
        [child beginAppearanceTransition:NO animated:animated];
    }
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self.child endAppearanceTransition];
}
```

[Customizing Appearance and Rotation Callback Behavior](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621389-shouldautomaticallyforwardappear)

Fixed my problem! Hope it would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned in another answer, the parent view controller might not call `viewWillAppear` etc. when `shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods` is set to `false`. `UINavigationController` and `UITabBarController` are known to do that. In this case, you need to call `beginAppearanceTransition(_ isAppearing: Bool, animated: Bool)` on the child view controller with `isAppearing` set to `true` when the view appears and vice versa.

You have to place these calls at appropriate places in your code, normally when you add and remove your child view controller.

Don't forget to call `endAppearanceTransition` on your child view controller when your custom transition has ended, otherwise `viewDidAppear` and `viewDidDisappear` are not called.

Answer (score 3):

Per Apple (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html), the correct order of API calls to add a child view controller is:

```
[self addChildViewController:childVC];
[self.view addSubview:childVC.view];
[childVC didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

But I still had the problem where viewWillAppear in the child VC was not sporadically getting called. My issue was that there was a race condition that could cause the code above to get executed *before* viewDidAppear in the container view controller was called. Ensuring that viewDidAppear had already been called (or deferring the addition of the child VC until it was) solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are correct, but in case it helps someone - if you override `loadView` in the child view controller, then none of the other UIViewController methods get called.

Took me some time to realize why my code wasn't running properly, until I realized that I had accidentally overridden `loadView` instead of `viewDidLoad`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your **parent** VC is a **UINavigationViewController** (or any other container). In this case the **shouldAutomaticallyForwardAppearanceMethods** is **False** and the appearance methods are not called.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your questions and your description.
My problem was similar to this only.

CustomTabBarController -> CustomUINavigationController -> RootViewcontroller

viewWillAppear of CustomUINavigationController and RootViewController are not getting called unless you switched to another tab and come back.

The solution is call super.viewWillAppear(animated: true)

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    **super.viewWillAppear(true)**
}
```

I struggled for more than a day for this small mistake.

Answer (score 0):

View appearance methods also will not get forwarded if your view controller hasn't loaded its view. This could happen if you override `loadView` in your child view controller, and the view is already added to the view hierarchy.

In that case, you could do

```
addChild(childVC)
childVC.loadViewIfNeeded()
childVC.didMove(toParent: self)
```