# viewWillAppear not called in subordinate view

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` which loads a subview from a nib and adds it to a subview in its view hierarchy. Now this is working all fine in the iPhone story board, but in the iPad one although I do see the view but as the `viewWillAppear` is not called the `UIImageView` on the view is not initialised.

Here's the code from the main viewcontroller (the one that loads the subview)

```
SubViewController *controller = [[SubViewController alloc] init];
NSArray *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"x"] owner:controller options:nil];
UIView *subView = bundle[0];
[self addChildViewController:controller];

if (isPhone)
{
    CGRect frame;
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame.origin.y = 0;
    frame.size = self.scrollView.frame.size;
    view.frame = frame;
    [self.scrollView addSubview:view];
 }
 else
 {
     view.frame = self.viewSlot.frame;
     [self.viewSlot addSubview:view];
 }
```

The only difference is on the iPhone it is added to a `UIScrollView` whereas on the iPad it is added to a `UIView`.

`viewSlot` and `scrollView` are both outlets which are properly initialised and work. Even on the iPad I do see my view (I've changed its background colour) it's only the initialisation (`viewWillAppear`) that does not run.

Comment: Put your relevant code here :)

Comment: YOu mean to say you are adding a 'viewcontroller.view' as a subview of other viewcontroller?

Comment: let's read tea-leaves

Comment: As others have stated, you need to post the relevant code.  Given your claim to be adding views (as opposed to view controllers), the mysterious part is actually the fact that `viewWillAppear` is being called on iPhone, not that it's not being called on iPad.

Comment: Guys, you are right, this question was half cooked. I've added some code, hope it's ok now.

Comment: A similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235284/uiviewcontroller-viewwillappear-not-called-when-adding-as-subview. As for now I haven't found any better solution than calling viewWillAppear manually. Which is strange as this is working on the iPhone.

Comment: Also checked `viewDidLayoutSubviews` not called either (called only on iPhone). This is interesting, as this is something that is a documented technique. And actually quite useful, as you may want to assemble views out of smaller subviews occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of playing I've managed to get to the bottom of this. First of all I chose to initialise the controller in a different manner:

```
SubViewController *controller = [[SubViewController alloc] initWithNibName:[@"X" stringByAppendingString:idiom] bundle:nil];
```

I've got an exception that revealed the problem: the `view` outlet wasn't set. Lesson of this story: don't just `alloc` - `init` a controller, use the `initWithNibName` initialiser. It's still weird that due to some not yet discovered difference between iPhone/iPad the earlier approach still worked on the iPhone.