# UIPageViewController Child's viewWillAppear: & viewDidAppear: transition calls

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, transition

How does one ensure that the `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` (and other view transition methods) are called on a `UIPageViewController's` child `ViewControllers`?

In my case, the view transition methods are adequately called on all except for the very `firstViewController` that the `UIPageViewController` opens to. On that `firstViewController`, the `viewDidAppear:` and `viewWillAppear:` methods are actually called BEFORE the `UIPageViewController's` view transition methods. And then as one starts scrolling, the `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` methods are called as one would expect for the new view controllers.

Here is my structure: I have a `BossViewController` that contains an `OrganizerViewController` (a couple different organizers, actually, but that is irrelevant). The `OrganizerViewController` contains a `UIPageViewController`, which contains a series of `CustomViewControllers`. My code adequately calls the child view transition methods as per apple (**https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html**) for the interactions between the `BossViewController` and the `OrganizerViewController` (fully functional, perfectly so). The problem lies somewhere between the `OrganizerViewController`, it's child `UIPageViewController`, and it's first child `CustomPageViewController`.

I have tried calling `beginAppearanceTransition:` and endAppearanceTransition: within the UIPageViewController's `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` - but that resulted in an 'unbalanced calls' error log to console.

Here is the `UIPageViewController` set up code, all of which is in the `OrganizerViewController`:

```
- (void)configurePVC
{
    NSDictionary *key = @{UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey : @([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width * 0.5)};
_pvc = [[AVSCustomPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
                                       navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:key];
    self.pvc.delegate = self;
    self.pvc.dataSource = self;

    _pvcArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    CustomViewController *daily = (CustomViewController *)[self viewControllerAtIndex:6];
    self.index = 6;

    [self.pvcArray addObject:daily];

    [self.pvc setViewControllers:self.pvcArray
                   direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward
                    animated:YES
                  completion:nil];

    [self addChildViewController:self.pvc];
    [self.dailyContainerView addSubview:self.pvc.view];
    self.pvc.view.frame = self.dailyContainerView.bounds;
    [self.pvc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = [(CustomViewController *)viewController index];
    if (index == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    index--;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSUInteger index = [(CustomViewController *)viewController index];
    if (index == 6) {
        return nil;
    }
    index++;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
- (UIViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    CustomViewController *viewController = [[CustomViewController alloc] init];
    viewController.index = index;


    return viewController;
}
```

Comment: I met same problem now... Have you solved it ?

Comment: I am also interested in a solution for this ? Did you try to call `addChildViewController` after adding the view as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18235284/uiviewcontroller-viewwillappear-not-called-when-adding-as-subview